# How to make an object move on a Mobius strip?

Tags: mesh, path

I have Mobius strip and a sphere. I want the sphere to move on the strips surface, like on a path. How can I do this?

I've tried drawing curves, but I can't create the whole path at once and I've tried joining drawed pieces but the sphere moves just on the first drawed curve. I've tried joining two circles but also the sphere goes just on one of them. There is a way to create a mobius nod directly but it doesn't match the shape and I can't make it match. Can I somehow draw the path by code? 
I'm very new to this so if there's an easier way I would appreciate it.

Tryed making edges the path, didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a Bezier Curve. Open it (it shouldn't be closed). Tilt one end 180°. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>
   The Curve should resemble the twist of the moebius strip.
   [image]
2. Add a **Follow Path Constraint** to the object. Check **Fixed Position** and set a key with the **offset** at `0` and `1`.
   [image]
3. Select the created keyframes and make them linear. <kbd>T</kbd> > <kbd>L</kbd>
   Then make the graph cyclic. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Make Cyclic*
   [image]
   [image]
4. Set a key on the first frame of the rotation. <kbd>I</kbd>
   Set a key after the second keyframe of the *offset* on the rotation with the object rotated 180°, making it ready for the second circulation.
   Set the new keys to constant interpolation. <kbd>T</kbd> > <kbd>C</kbd>
   [image]

Wheeee!
[image]

[image]

Comment: My main problem is to draw the curve to the shape, so that the object would go on the center of the strip. Maybe I can use segments from your answer. Thank you anyway. : )

Comment: @K.D. or rebuild the strip using a curve combined with a mesh with the curve modifier.

Comment: I don't know what curve modifier is (newbie), but I can maybe make it thinner if that is what you meant?

Comment: @K.D. Not quite, but if your problem persists, edit your question to add more detail, describing what you mean by *the object would go on the center of the strip* or ask a new question and mark this one as solved.